# How to use `Array.prototype.filter` to remove one item from an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I don't quite understand this function, like what do you filter out and the way it work...can anybody help me to expalin this? I'm a begginer and i need your help! Thank you so much btw!

Function:

```
removeFromCart =(product) => {
  const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice()
  this.setState({
    cartItems: cartItems.filter((x)=>x.id!==product.id)
  })
}
```

Comment: only allowed those whos id doesnt match, if match then not included, like alcohol allowed to only `age>18` if not  then not allowed `filtered out`

Comment: Thank you, i kinda get it now but my function isn't working because id is not defined. Can you help me adress the problem? Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-19huj?file=/src/components/Cart.js

Comment: FYI: Similar to the search we did for your `addToCart` function, you'll want to first check if there *is* an item to remove and only remove and update state if there is, otherwise you make the app and React do work and trigger a rerender for nothing.

Comment: @naha Check my updated answer. You're not passing the product to the remove function.

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) expects a callback that returns a boolean.

If the callback returns `true`, the element gets pushed to the new array and if it returns false, the element will not be pushed.

`const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice()` creates a new array and can be removed as `filter` creates a new array anyway.

---

```
cartItems.filter((x)=>x.id!==product.id)
```

If we consider the above snippet, the returned value is `x.id!==product.id` because if the id matches, `x.id !== product.id` will evaluate to `false` and returning `false` will remove the product.

---

**Update:**

You also seem to have an issue with passing the product to the function. Fixed that and here's the updated sandbox:

[image: Edit redux shop cart (forked)]

```
<button className="button" onClick={() => props.removeFromCart(item)}>
  Remove
</button>
```

Comment: do we need to do `({...this.state, cartItems: prevState.})`

Comment: @AshishKamble In class components, `setState` merges the updated property without overwriting. So, it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the longer version of that code, you might get confused because your version has a lot of shortcuts and bad variable name. (comments)

```
removeFromCart = (product) => {
  const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.filter((item) => {
     return item.id !== product.id;
  });


  this.setState({
    cartItems: t
  })
}
```

let's know this:

```
const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice()
```

First, you don't need this one as `filter` already returns a new array
usually you use `slice` to create a copy (portion) of that array (usually we pass arguments on it and I've rarely seen a usage where the dev uses it as a "clone" function. [You can read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```
  const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.filter((item) => {
     return item.id !== product.id;
  });
```

for this one, I renamed your variable `x` into `item` to make it more understandable. Since `cartItems` is an array, this function will go through each items then create a new array where the item id is not the same as product id (`return item.id !== product.id`). [Read more about filters here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
  this.setState({
    cartItems
  })
```

you pass the newly created `cartItems` to update your state.

Answer (score 0):

In you code the [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function is use to create a copy of the state `cartItems` which is an array. the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function is use to filter the array and return only item which match the condition which is test in the callback function passed to the filter function.

Precisely you are setting the `cartItems` array to be equal to an array which contains only item which `id` is different than the `id` of the product pass as argument of the `removeFromCart` function.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two things to note.**

1. First of all, we are taking a shallow copy of the array by using `slice()` method of javascript. This is done so that

> we do not mutate the original state

(Which is a foundational principle in React)

```
const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice(); // We have the copy of original state
```

The same can we achieved with *ES6 spread operator* though (which is recommended in React)

```
const cartItems = [...this.state.cartItems];// This does the same what slice() does
```

2. Second part is the logic in **filter method** which is a Higher Order Function.

   ```
   cartItems.filter((x)=>x.id!==product.id)
   ```

For each item in your array (Which is each object in your array), this callback function runs

```
(x)=>x.id!==product.id
```

in each iteration and checks whether `item.id` (i.e Current Object's id) is not equal to the Id selected. So, All the items are filtered and shown expect for the item where product's id matches the item's id (This one is not shown in DOM) all other.

Finally, you are updating your state with the filtered items and hence your functionality works as expected :)

Would recommend you to learn about Higher Order Functions, such as `map()`, `filter()`, `reduce()` since they are used a lot in React and Javascript frameworks, since you are a just starting.

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
```

Comment: The first part is completely unnecessary and array spread syntax is not recommended. It's just easier to use.

Comment: I respect what you said, But I disagree with it. I believe spread operator is more recommended :) and I have been using it in all my projects. 
These are all my Projects and I have worked on React a lot
https://github.com/emmeiwhite?tab=repositories

Comment: You seem to miss the point. OP doesn't need to spread or slice as filter creates a new array anyway.

Comment: I just recommend it after explaining what `slice()` does :)

Answer (score -1):

In your `Cart.js`, you have to change call function and pass item, `props.removeFromCart(item)}`

```
<button
  className="button"
  onClick={() => props.removeFromCart(item)}
>
  Remove
</button>
```

and in `App.js`, keep same or,

```
  removeFromCart = (product) => {
    //const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice();
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
       cartItems: prevState.cartItems.filter((x) => x._id !== product._id)
    }));
  };
```

this do exactly what needs to be done, but it removes selected cart elements